# Italicize cited only authors in person index

Tags: biblatex, indexing, xindy, authorindex

I want to have mixed persons index and cited works authors index. Authors which appears **only** in citations must be italicized in the index. Other persons (and authors which appears also in main text) are normal.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,indexing=cite]{biblatex} %for digital version 
\bibliography{\jobname}

\usepackage[truexindy,splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=persons,program=truexindy,options=-M texindy]

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
    author  = "Greenwild, Dirk",
    title   = "Yellow pages",
    year    = "1998",
}
@book{book2,
    author    = "Jordan, Peter",
    title     = "Math in the world",
    year      = "1996",
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \nameparts{#1}
  \usebibmacro{index:name}
    {\index[persons]}
    {\itshape\namepartfamily\normalfont} 
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix} 
    {\namepartsuffix}%
    }

\begin{document}

Foo\index[persons]{Smith, Joe}. Foo\cite{book1}. Jordan\index[persons]{Jordan, Peter} foo\cite{book2}.

\printindex[persons]

\end{document}
```

[image: index]

There are some problems. First - I can't italicize first name.
`{\itshape\namepartfamily\normalfont}` italizes last name, but `{\itshape\namepartgiven\normalfont}` leads to errors. The only way to italicize both is

```
{\itshape\namepartfamily} 
{\namepartgiven}
{\normalfont\namepartprefix}
```

But now author who is not only cited but also indexed manually from text in the index appears twice (Jordan Peter).
[image: index2]

How can I merge them and make both first and last name italic?

## Solution (?):

Finally I get it worked by redefining `\mkbibindexname` command:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mkbibindexname}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\ifdefvoid{#3}{}{#3 }%
     \@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{, #2}%
     \actualoperator
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\MakeCapital{#3} }%
     #1%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{, #2}}
    {\@firstofone \textit{#1}% here added \textit
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\ }%removes comma between first and last name
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{ \textit{#2}}% here added \textit
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{ #3}}}
\makeatother
```

Result:

[image: good one]

This solution works (Greenwild Dirk is italicized because he appears only in the citation, Smith Joe is not italicized because he appears only in the main text, Jordan Peter is not italicized because he appears in both text and citation).
Perhaps there is some more elegant solution?

Comment: In my opinion you should share the solution you found by answering your own question. Where it is now it is not clearly visible